# What is the server side issue that could cause the MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel

I use `Route::delete()` methods in my routes file. Until I moved the app to the new server I had no issues by using this method, but now I get the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I used the app for about **6 months without any problems**. But now I get this on every delete process. Of course when I change the method to `post` and add a hidden var `_method` it works. But I wonder what (setting) could cause this on the new server. Any ideas?

**The exception detail:**

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 5
```

Comment: Open up git and see what was recently changed. There is your solution.

Comment: Is there any change in the client which fires the request.? coz html forms doesnt support put, patch and delete

Comment: Try by clearing cache `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means the route is not found for your http request.

Comment: But the route exists. Moreover it worked for 6months the only change was the server change. That is why I am suspicious about the server settings.

Comment: @Skeletor might be the issue with php version in server.see  [Server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation#server-requirements) for laravel.

Answer (score 1):

The methodNotAllowed exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

**Route::delete Example**:

```
Route::delete('empresas/eliminar/{id}', [
        'as' => 'companiesDelete',
        'uses' => 'CompaniesController@delete'
]);
```

Comment: But the route exists. Moreover it worked for 6months the only change was the server change. That is why I am suspicious about the server settings.

Comment: Did you change laravel version?

Comment: the version of laravel? No. Perhaps the php version may have changed but I don't think it would matter for this case.